# nginx as rate limiter based on http body

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm evaluating nginx to act as rate limiter for a multi tenancy REST API system. I need to limit API calls by tenant-id. 
For example i want to allow 100 r/s for tenant1 and only 50 r/s for tenant2.

It can be easily achived when there are differant urls like: "me.com/tenant1/api" and "me.com/tenant2/api" (with the location directive).

But, in my case the urls are the same for all tenants "me.com/api" (I can't change this). 
To find the tenant-id I need to extract a JSON attribute from the Body of the request, and then check the DB for the real tenant-id.

Is it possible to limit_req with my requirements?

Thank for the help!

Comment: If you can put that ID as an HTTP header then you should be able to do something like `limit_req_zone $http_tenant_id ...`.  Otherwise you might be able to use a [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) to extract that value out of $response_body.

Comment: thanks @FaisalMemon. sadly, i can't add http header. the only way to  find the tenant-id is by decoding the Base64 JSON body, extract some variable and search it in the DB (or cache).

Comment: To do something complex like that you'll likely have to use Lua: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#readme

Comment: I was hoping to find something less intrusive that lua thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to build another service *getTenant* for parsing the body and extracting the Tenant from the DB. This service is called internally by Nginx.
I'm not sure if that is the best nginx (/openresty) solution, but this is what i came up with:

```
limit_req_zone t1Limit zone=t1Zone:10m rate=200r/s;
limit_req_zone t2Limit zone=t2Zone:10m rate=90r/s;

server {

    location /api{
        content_by_lua_block {
            ngx.req.read_body();
            local reqBody = ngx.req.get_body_data()
            local res = ngx.location.capture("/getTenant", {method=ngx.HTTP_POST,body=reqBody});
            local tenantId= res.body;
            if tenantId== "none" then
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Tenant not found!");
                ngx.say(tenantId);
            else
                ngx.req.set_header("x_myTenantId", tenantId)
                local res2 = ngx.location.capture("/" .. tenantId .."/doApi", {method=ngx.HTTP_POST,body=reqBody});
                if res2.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then                      
                    ngx.say(res2.body);
                    ngx.exit(res2.status);
                else 
                    ngx.status = res2.status
                    ngx.exit(res2.status) 
                end
            end;
        }
    }

    location  /getTenant {
        internal; #this is not accessible from outside.            
        proxy_pass              http://UpStream1/getCustomer;
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }

    location /tenant1/doApi {
        internal; #this is not accessible from outside.
        # Proxy all requests to the AReqUpStream server group
        proxy_pass http://UpStream2/doApi;
        limit_req zone=tenant1Zone burst=25;            
        limit_req_log_level notice;
    }

    location /tenant2/doApi {
        internal; #this is not accessible from outside.     
        # Proxy all requests to the AReqUpStream server group
        proxy_pass http://UpStream2/doApi;
        limit_req zone=tenant2Zone burst=10 ;#nodelay;          
        limit_req_status 409;
        limit_req_log_level notice;
    }
}
```

Basically, when *me.com/api* is called, a new subrequest is issued to service */getTenant*. The response of that call is used to build another subrequest call to the */tenant[X]/doApi* service. That way i can define locations per tenant and provide different rate_limis to each.

Comments on that are more than welcome!